# ScrollController listener doesn't fire when pulling up a ListView in Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView and a Calendar above it. My plan is to expend the Calendar based on the ListView scroll state. I managed to handle all of that except one issue with Android.

```
ScrollController _scrollController;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_handleScroll);
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_handleScroll);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

void _handleScroll() {
    // Handle Scrolling here.
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Calendar(),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            children: <Widget>[
              ListViewItem(),
              ListViewItem(),
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The image below illustrate the issue!

### [image]

As you can see, pulling the ListView when the user didn't scroll down yet doesn't seem to trigger the _handleScroll at all. I think it's by design on Android. Any solutions or workaround to this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a CustomScrollView with Slivers, as explained here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/floating-app-bar

Comment: This won't work since the Calendar widget has its own methods to shrink/expand. Although this is a good feature I haven't heard of yet as I'm new to Flutter :)

Comment: @OtmanBouchari you can enclose your Calendar Widget in a SliverPersistentHeader widget. Simply manage the methods of expanding the calendar in a SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate. For a more precise explanation I would need to know the Calendar widget in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar package. I haven't learned about Slivers yet! Do you know of any good article about the subject? I'll really appreciate it :)